# Update DOM only when $scope data changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular js app, I noticed that the DOM updates any time I call a function. This happens even when the function did not change any $scope variable.

I'm using an ng-repeat to create a set of checkboxes as shown below.

HTML

```
<a ng-click="someFunction()" >Some Function</a>
<form action="/settings/save">
  <label>
    <input ng-repeat="option in settings.active" name="options[]" value="{{option}}" checked="checked" />
    {{option}}
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

JS

```
angular.module("myapp")
    .controller("settingsCtrl", function($scope, $loadServ){

    //$loadServ is a service for fetching data from the server
    $loadServ("/settings/load")
        .success(function(response){$scope.settings = response.data});

    $scope.someVariable = "something";
    $scope.someFunction = function(){
        //There's nothing here yet
    }
    //More code follows
})
```

I noticed that all the unchecked checkboxes are checked when the "Some Function" button is clicked. I inspected the DOM and realised that all the checkboxes were re-rendered when the button was clicked.

Is there a way to update the DOM only when the $scope changes?
Note: I can't use one way binding because the $scope.settings.active can be changed by some other function

Comment: you want something to happen only when you click on a button which calls your someFunction ?

Comment: can you create a plunker or jsbin with your test? it appears like a piece of DOM not controlled by angular (without ng-app, or without ng-controller, in specific point)

Comment: I don't want my DOM to be re-rendered when I call someFunction. This is because someFunction does not change the $scope. And I don't want to lose the checkbox customizations just because some other unrelated function was called

Comment: can you try with ng-repeat="option in settings.active track by $index"

Comment: I'm trying to replicate it in jsbin, but I've not been able to replicate the error. I think another part of the app may be causing the problem.

https://jsbin.com/yacujijogu/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

I've found the source of the error. It was caused by a filter that was applied far above the nodes